# How to change message of success when adding product to cart in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Well, the functionality of adding the product to the cart via ajax is 100% working, however a message below appears like this

[image]

Well, the code generated is this, automatic whenever the product is added to the cart successfully

```
<a href="http://www.shopurl.com/cart/" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="View Cart">View Cart</a>
```

I want to know how you can edit this particular line

Answer (score 0):

@credited to [helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking) on her answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863005/how-to-change-url-in-view-cart-button-in-woocommerce)

You can filter the checkout url via [woocommerce_get_checkout_url](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L1147)

```
function so_37863005_checkout_url( $url ){

    // Force SSL if needed
    $scheme = ( is_ssl() || 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_force_ssl_checkout' ) ) ? 'https' : 'http';
    $url = site_url( '/custom-page/', $scheme );

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'so_37863005_checkout_url', 10, 2 );
```

**Try this unique way**

```
function text_view_cart_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
switch ( $translated_text ) {
    case 'View Cart' :
        $translated_text = __( 'Check On Out', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
}
return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'text_view_cart_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: No works for me bro :/, my shop http://www.decsigner.com.br/projetos/loja/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me every time. Let me know if it works for you.

```
/**
 * @snippet       Edit "successfully added to your cart"
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=494
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 2.5.2
 */

add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'bbloomer_custom_add_to_cart_message' );

function bbloomer_custom_add_to_cart_message() {

global $woocommerce;
$return_to  = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'));
$message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forwards">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __('Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
return $message;
}
```

Comment: No works for me bro :/, my shop http://www.decsigner.com.br/projetos/loja/