# Change Name and URL of "Add to cart" (Enable WooCommerce AJAX)

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce

I have seen that there are many questions about changing the "Add to cart" button in WooCommerce and "Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives". My question is aimed at mixing ([image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvAY7.jpg)). How can we preserve the first "Add to cart", and replace the second one with a "Checkout" + direct URL?

I don't want the customer to go to the Checkout directly (very good article about that at [Jeroen Sormani's webiste](https://jeroensormani.com/redirect-users-after-add-to-cart/)), but I would like to offer them the option to do so after adding the product to the cart (My products can only be purchased individually: it makes no sense to have one more "Add to cart").

Stack overflow has some tips like "[How to change url in "View Cart" button in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863005/how-to-change-url-in-view-cart-button-in-woocommerce)", but it does not include the rename we want.

I have Code Snippets installed because I know you have to touch php code, but I don't know how to mix it up to get this.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the Code Snippets plugin or your theme's functions.php file. (I recommend using a child theme)

Change text and url of 'view cart' button on shop and product archive pages.

```php
// Change text and url after click of add to cart button on shop and product archive pages.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'so70502187_replace_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function so70502187_replace_add_to_cart_button( $params, $handle ) {
  switch ($handle) {
    case 'wc-add-to-cart':
      $params['cart_url'] = esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() );
      $params['i18n_view_cart'] = esc_attr__( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' );
      break;
  }
  return $params;
}
```

Change text and url on 'item added to cart' notification on single product pages.

```php
// Change text and url on 'item added to cart' notification on single product pages.
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'so70502187_single_replace_add_to_cart_button');
function so70502187_single_replace_add_to_cart_button() {
  if ( 'yes' !== get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
    return sprintf( '<a href="%s" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ), esc_html__( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html__( 'The item has been added to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }
}
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I put both in Code Snipets, but after activating it I got a "There has been a critical error on this website." (The web was visible, but it was broken and all the elements were misplaced).

I removed the first and the error was gone, but the second (individual product page) didn't change anything.

Comment: I've fixed the code.